# Is it possible to use CCMP as cipher type on ESP32's softAP mode?

Tags: wifi, esp32, espressif, softap

Currently I'm starting softAP mode on ESP32 with WPA2_PSK as auth type(as WPA3 is not supported for softAP). When I am trying to connect my iPhone to the softAP, iOS gives a warning that WiFi security is weak as it is using WPA2(TKIP). Instead it is asking to configure the AP to use WPA2(AES). I learnt that I need to use CCMP as cipher type instead of TKIP. But I cannot find any API to set cipher type for softAP. Is it supported? Or should I use only TKIP as encryption type? Thanks in advance!